# Javascript not running before submitting to php file

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I'm learning more about PHP/Javascript, trying to set up a basic website. I've got the full thing up and running, but there is no validation on registration and whatnot. I'm trying to use Javascript to validate the form before submitting it, but it's  not working for me. Here is my page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
OK = false;
function validateEmail() {
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["myemail"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if(atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}

function notShortUsername() {
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["myusername"].value;
    if(x.value.length < 6) {
        // set the focus to this input
        OK = false;
    }
    OK = true;
}

function notShortPassword() {
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["mypassword"].value;
    if(x.value.length < 6) {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        // set the focus to this input
        OK = false;
    }
    OK = true;
}

function validate () {
    notShortUsername();
    notShortPassword();
    validateEmail();

    if(OK) {
        form.submit();
        return true;
    } else {
        //do something else
        alert("You did it wrong!");
        return false;
    }
} 
</script>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="registervalidation.php" onsubmit="return validate">
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="78">Username</td>
          <td width="6">:</td>
          <td width="294">
            <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>
            <input name="myemail" type="text" id="myemail">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Complete Registration">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Cancel">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've also tried using this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

The issue with it is it won't validate when the item loses focus, and still submits the php anyways.

Comment: Please reduce the problem to its minimal form.

Comment: I hope you aren't validating *just* on the client.

Comment: No, I'm also doing some validation on the php that pushes back to the registration page, but I want some validation on the client side that checks formatting before it runs the php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onsubmit="return validate();"
```

Do **not** forget the `();`

Comment: Yeah, that didn't fix it. It's still running to the php.

Comment: @SpencerCole Try this: `onsubmit="validate(); return false;"`

Comment: No. Still running to the php.

Comment: My issue is that it's not Java or Objective-C, this stuff is all foreign to me.

Comment: @SpencerCole again im no debugger, take your code apart piece by piece and you will find the error.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
var x = document.forms["form1"]["myusername"].value;
if(x.value.length < 6) {
```

to:

```
var x = document.forms["form1"]["myusername"].value;
if(x.length < 6) {
```

and this:

```
var x = document.forms["form1"]["mypassword"].value;
if(x.value.length < 6) {
```

to:

```
var x = document.forms["form1"]["mypassword"].value;
if(x.length < 6) {
```

In each case, `var x` already contains the value so you get the length directly by `x.length`

Answer (score 0):

Test your validate function outside the form submit:

```
<a href="#" onclick="validate();">test</a>
```

You'll see an error in the console letting you know x isn't defined.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

So the script stops executing and never returns false, which allows the form to post.